# Knockout $parent undefined

Tags: knockout.js

Viewmodel is something like this:

```
Main_Vm = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.ChildViewModel = new OtherViewModel();
  self.ParProp = ko.observable();
};
var vmMain = new Main_Vm();

ko.applyBindings(vmMain, document.getElementById('mainArea'));
ko.applyBindings(vmMain.ChildViewModel, document.getElementById('childArea'));
```

If i try to call $parent within the childArea, I get a $parent is undefined error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why the `$parent` should be definied? You are directly binding to `vmMain.ChildViewModel` so KO won't know that you've meant to have `vmMain` as your parent... So you should bind directly to your whole view model with `ko.applyBindings(vmMain)` and use `data-bind"with: ChildViewModel"` on your `childArea`...

Comment: Ohh, the with binding is new to me. This gives me something to explore. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, nemesv. Using the with binding worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$parent` is only populated if you are inside in a "child" binding context which you have normally when you are using the `foreach` or the `with` binding. You can read more about the binding contexts are working [here in the documentation.](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)

In your current code because you are directly applying the bindings on your `vmMain.ChildViewModel` Knockout is not creating a child context for you so it does not know about your parent `vmMain` object.

You can create a direct reference in your `OtherViewModel` to your `Main_Vm`

or you can use the [`with` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html):

```
Main_Vm = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.ChildViewModel = new OtherViewModel();
  self.ParProp = ko.observable();
};
var vmMain = new Main_Vm();

ko.applyBindings(vmMain);
```

And your view should look like:

```
<div id="mainArea">
 //.. do something with ParProp
</div>
<div id="childArea" data-bind="with: ChildViewModel">
  // do something with ChildViewModel's properties
  // or here you can use $parent to access your vmMain properties
</div>
```